# Can we use Azure Active Directory to remove local Domain Controller?

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id

I have done some research and I cannot get a straight answer so far.

I am aware of Azure active directory domain services . But I wonder if it or anything Microsoft Azure has can delete or remove a local Domain Controller?

By local I presume it means on-premise?

I wonder with a hyrbrid structure in place, (i.e. part Azure and part on-premise Active Directory) , if there is a way for Azure Active Directory to delete a local (on-premise) Domain Controller?

Please advise.

Thank you very much.

Comment: From the point of View its possible buti would suggest a hybrid setup in case of a Internet outage

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Active Directory service can not delete a domain controller.

The closest that you can get is having a domain controller in Azure running on a VM that has a connection back to your network.  You can then demote and remove a domain controller that is on premise.

I wouldn't recommend just having one in azure, I would distribute between on premise and off premise depending on your requirements.

Comment: I agree to you as its Best practice in my point of View

Comment: illandous and djdomi,

Thank you very much for your answer.

I have a couple of questions:

When you said "connection back to your network" , what kind of setup needs to be in place between Azure Active Directory and on-premise Active Directory for that kind of connection to happen?

When you said "demote and remove a domain controller that is on premise" , are all these demotion and removal done via Azure Active Directory if said connection is in place?

Please advise.

Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way , why is it not best practice to run domain controller in Azure on a VM that has a connection back to the network with the power to demote then remove an on-premise domain controller?

Comment: @goughgough The connection "back to your network" could be a VPN, MPLS, or Express route or a mix.  I didn't want to make it specific.  I also wouldn't want to run an active directory domain controller off-premise for an office location.  If you lose internet, you lose your ability to authenticate to local network sources unless you have a domain controller on your LAN.